# how do you rotate an image to the position of the mouse in c#?

Tags: c#, windows, silverlight, windows-phone-7, rotation

i am making a game where there's a tank. I need to know how i can rotate the turret to the position of the mouse, or the position of a touch (windows phone 7). I would also like to limit the rotations, e.g the turret can rotate past 90° and 270°.

What's the easiest and most efficient way to do this?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Easiest and most efficient: Post a question on Stackoverflow and get someone to write the code for you.  A harder less efficient way is to: Learn some basic trigonometry and write some code.  Its an interesting enough but easy enough requirement that I'm sure some one will give you the answer.  If not post here what you have tried and we'll try to help you.

Answer (score 4):

In loose terms, knowing the position of your tank, you can get the position of the touch from the relevant event, and then work out the angle between the two using simple trigonometry. Having worked out the angle, you can then apply whatever logic you want to limit it to a specific range.

For detailed information about the touch events in Windows Phone 7, Jeff Prosise has an excellent series of blog posts:

- [Building Touch Interfaces for Windows Phones, Part 1](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2011/01/14/building-touch-interfaces-for-windows-phones-part-1.aspx)
- [Building Touch Interfaces for Windows Phones, Part 2](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2011/01/14/building-touch-interfaces-for-windows-phones-part-2.aspx)
- [Building Touch Interfaces for Windows Phones, Part 3](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2011/01/19/building-touch-interfaces-for-windows-phones-part-3.aspx)
- [Building Touch Interfaces for Windows Phones, Part 4](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2011/01/20/building-touch-interfaces-for-windows-phones-part-4.aspx)