# GestureListener in ScrollViewer on Windows phone 7 does not work

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

I have a prblem: If I enter this kind of xaml:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1">
    <ScrollViewer Name="scrolViewer" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" BorderBrush="AliceBlue"
            BorderThickness="5" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Image Name="mapImage" CacheMode="BitmapCache" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5 0.5">
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform x:Name="transform" />
            </Image.RenderTransform >
            <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                <toolkit:GestureListener PinchStarted="OnPinchStarted" PinchDelta="OnPinchDelta" />
            </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
```

Gestures does not work, but image slides as it is expected to.
If I remove  tag - gestures begin to work.
How do I enable guestures to zoom and rotate image inside scrollviewer or how do I create my own scrollviewer based on gestures.
Thanx in advance!

Comment: can you try to add a Background="Transparent" to your scrollviewer?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure putting your image in a `ScrollViewer` is a great idea as it's possible the gesture handling between `ScrollViewer` and `GestureListener` will compete.

See [Jeff Prosise's blog](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2011/01/20/building-touch-interfaces-for-windows-phones-part-4.aspx) for an example of how to zoom/rotate using `GestureListener`. The whole blog post series is very useful if you want to learn more about WP7 touch.

(Thanks to Derek's answer to a previous [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017912/how-do-you-rotate-an-image-to-the-position-of-the-mouse-in-c/5018095#5018095).)

Comment: Thanx, Paul. Interesting article. The thing is that I've once implemented all this stuff in wm 6.5 with zoomings, slidings etc. All on mouse down-mousemove-mouseup. I've implemented even cutom moseclicks, mousedoubleclicks, tapandhold, etc... It was lots of code. I am pretty shure there should be elegant solution on wp7. Those guestures are fine and simple but I do not feel it right writing code even for sliding animations doubletapping, moving image inside screen again if its outside of it. I am pretty shure there should be an elegant solution like picture with gestures inside scrollviewer.